# Azure Api Connections: Change the connection name

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I created a couple of Azure API connections and it allows me to change the display name, but there is no way to change the name itself. Apparently, it automatically creates the connections based on the connection type. Is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could deploy API connector and change its name with `Template`. If you already have a API connector, click it then choose **Automation script** and click **Deploy**.Like the below pic shows.

[image]

Now choose Edit template and for convenience delete the parameters and resources you don't want to use. In here you could change `defaultValue` as the name  ,after modify the template would be like the pic shows, then click save. I fthe name in **SETTING** is not changed you also could change it here.

[image]

And the result shows the API name is not the original default name.

[image]

**Note: This way is only used to deploy the API connectors.**

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: "Parameter value missing" How does one know what parameters are considered missing and supply them in the template?

Comment: I'm still facing issue like "The API <name> could not be found. (Code: APINotFound)